# How to call a function when the Enter button is pressed in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

So I have a `ui-select` option code below that allows the user to search for items in a drop-down and it works well. But in the scenario when the user pressed the  **ENTER** button, my function right now is not executed.

```
<ui-select 
    v-model="groupName"
    has-search
    @keydown="createGroup($event)"
></ui-select>
```

Sample output is below:

[image]

and in my **METHODS**, I have this one:

```
createGroup: function(evt){
    console.log(evt);
},
```

Anyone has an idea how to do this?

Comment: `@keyup.enter="createGroup"` https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Key-Modifiers

Comment: @EmileBergeron Do I have to modify something from my function? Because it's still not working.

Comment: @downvoter, Would you mind explaining you've downvoted this one?

Comment: Where does the `ui-select` component come from? There's a good chance it captures the `Enter` key and for some reason, isn't emitting it out. The component documentation and / or source code may help

Comment: Phil is asking the right question, I showed you how to do it with Vue, but you're using a specific component which doesn't necessarily emit `keyup` events.

Comment: @Phil I have a pre-defined `<ui-select>` in my local, as I've checked, it's displaying the keys I'm pressing but not the enter key, I mean just the character keys.

Comment: @ramedju I think you misunderstood. Did you write the `ui-select` component code or is it from some 3rd party library? If the latter, which library is it? If the former, please show the component's code

Comment: Is it [Keen-UI](https://github.com/JosephusPaye/Keen-UI)? If so, the issue is as expected ~ [`@keydown.enter.prevent="openDropdown"`](https://github.com/JosephusPaye/Keen-UI/blob/master/src/UiSelect.vue#L28). A possible solution is to use something other than `keydown` like `keyup` or `keypress`

Comment: @Phil Yes. it is Keen-UI. Already tried both your suggestions but still not working.

Comment: In `ui-select` sources i found that it stops propagation of event with `@keydown.enter.prevent.stop` when user selects some option. So I think you can not listen to this event.

Comment: @MaxSinev Is there any other way or work-around for this one?

Answer (score 1):

As I mention in comments for question, there is no way to listen enter event because of `ui-select` **stops event bubbling** on option selection - [Source](https://github.com/JosephusPaye/Keen-UI/blob/next/src/UiSelect.vue#L70).
I just can advise to rethink design and if you need to create something when user select an option of `ui-select` you can listen `input` event and do some extra stuff or event prevent selecting some option. *This is more (Vue-correct)data-driven design I think.*

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   colourStrings: ["Red","Blue", "Green"],
    select1: "",
    log: ""
  },
  methods: {
   setValue(val) {
      // ui-select call setValue with our empty string when rendered
     val && this.createGroup(val);
     this.select1 = val;
    },
    createGroup(val) {
     // some stuff
     this.log += val + " created!\n"
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/keen-ui@1.0.1/dist/keen-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/keen-ui@1.0.1/dist/keen-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="app">
  <ui-select
                label="Favourite colour"
                placeholder="Select a colour"
                :options="colourStrings"
                :value="select1"
                @input="setValue"
            ></ui-select>
            <pre>{{log}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but what I want is, if the item is not available from the drop-down menu, he can add it by pressing enter or any other way, except button :S

Comment: @ramedju Oh, does it need to press enter in search input to add option? If so you can check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/89r8yq2u/) it will show Add button when no results found.

Comment: This is perfect! Gonna try this out in a while. Thanks.

Comment: Weeew, currently having issue, cos in the `<div slot=no-results>` is not working on my end :S Still no add button displayed, but this is already a perfect solution.